# vuex store state update value in middleware check-auth.js, but can't get the updated value in vue view

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I am using nuxtjs for myProject, i useing axios to get auth information in minddleware/check-auth.js and commit the flag to store.state.isSEPCNavFlag;
But i can't get the updated  isSEPCNavFlag value in vue view, the value is always null.
anyone can help me? please...

store/index.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import echarts from 'echarts'
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { saveToken, delToken } from '@/utils/auth'
Vue.use(Vuex)

export const strict = true

export const state = () => ({
  authUser: null,
  user: '',
  locale: null,
  locales: ['zh', 'en'],
  isMenuHidden: true,
  isSEPCNavFlag:null,
})

export const mutations = {
  SET_SEPCFLAG: function (state, isSEPCNavFlag) {
      state.isSEPCNavFlag = isSEPCNavFlag
    },

  SET_TOKEN: function (state, token) {
    state.authUser = token
  },
  SET_USER: function (state, user) {
    state.user = user
  },
  SET_MENUS: function (state, menus) {
    state.menus = menus
  },
  SET_LANG (state, locale) {
    if (state.locales.indexOf(locale) !== -1) {
      state.locale = locale
    }
  },
  TOGGLE_MENU_HIDDEN: function (state) {
    state.isMenuHidden = !state.isMenuHidden
  }
}
```

minddleware/check-auth.js

```
async function toNavTO(token,store) {
  var returnData = await funcAsync(token)
  var ACNameIndex = returnData.data.indexOf("<AccountName>");
  var navFlag = true;
  if(ACNameIndex == -1){
        navFlag=false
    }
  store.commit('SET_SEPCFLAG', navFlag)
}
```

index.vue

```
mounted(){
  this.login();
},
methods: {
    login(){
      let navFlag = this.$store.state.isSEPCNavFlag;
      console.log(navFlag);
```

this.$store.state.isSEPCNavFlag value always null.

[mutations SET_SEPCFLAG console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVQ5Y.png)

Comment: have you tried putting some console.log() inside the SET_SEPCFLAG mutation function to see if it is called at all ?

Comment: @Istopopoki   yes, i have add a console.log after SET_SEPCFLAG mutation, and the state.isSEPCNavFlag  has changed to new value.

Comment: Dont import Vuex and vue in your store/index file

Comment: @Aldarund hi, i delete Vuex and vue import in store/index file, but the 
 state.isSEPCNavFlag  in vue file also null.

Comment: Create a reproduction on codesandbox please